# Ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError: Bootstrap is not defined

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Я хочу показать модальное окно вот так

```
<div class="notification">
    <div class="modal fade" id="errorModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="errorModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="errorModalLabel">{title}</h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              {error}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script src="{THEME}/assets/js/notification.js"></script>
    <script>function error_modalwindow(){
        const modal = new Bootstrap.Modal(document.querySelector('#errorModal'));
        modal.show();}error_modalwindow();</script>
</div>
```

но пишет то что `Uncaught ReferenceError: Bootstrap is not defined`, но я импортировал Bootstrap в самом конце html файла

```
script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: Нужно сначала загрузить библиотеку, а потом использовать класс из нее. Т.е. просто загрузить скрипт перед использованием, либо дописать проверку на наличие. В вашем случае перенесите загрузку выше.

Comment: сделал, всё равно не получается @СерверУсеинов

Comment: а откуда ты взял этот код `new Bootstrap.Modal`?

Answer (score 0):

У меня так работает:

```
<head runat="server">
...
...
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" 
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```